# Javascript regex between string delimiters

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I have the following string:

```
%||1234567890||Joe||% some text winter is coming %||1234567890||Robert||%
```

PROBLEM: I am trying to match all occurrences between %||....||% and process those substring matches

MY REGEX: `/%([\s\S]*?)(?=%)/g`

MY CODE

```
var a = "%||1234567890||Joe||% some text winter is coming %||1234567890||Robert||%";

var pattern = /%([\s\S]*?)(?=%)/g;

a.replace( pattern, function replacer(match){
    return match.doSomething();
} );
```

Now the patterns seems to be selecting the everything between the first and last occurrence of %||  .... %||

MY
[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c530g9zs/)

WHAT I NEED:

I want to iterate over the matches

%||1234567890||Joe||%

AND

%||1234567890||Robert||%

and do something

Comment: Try replacing the pattern with `/%\|\|([\s\S]*?)(?=\|\|%)/g` or even `/%\|\|([\s\S]*?)\|\|%/g` - https://regex101.com/r/ugkkNa/1. Then use the `a = a.replace(/pattern/g, function ($0, $1) {return ...;})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a callback inside a `String#replace` and modify the pattern to only match what is inside `%||` and `||%` like this:

```js
var a = "%||1234567890||Joe||% some text winter is coming %||1234567890||Robert||%";
var pattern = /%\|\|([\s\S]*?)\|\|%/g;
a = a.replace( pattern, function (match, group1){
    var chunks = group1.split('||');
    return "{1}" + chunks.join("-") + "{/1}";
} );
console.log(a);
```

The `/%\|\|([\s\S]*?)\|\|%/g` pattern will match:

- `%\|\|` - a `%||` substring
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Capturing group 1 matching any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `\|\|%` - a `||%` substring
- `/g` - multiple times.

Comment: Simply brilliant! Thank you Wiktor :)

Answer (score 0):

Because he tries to take as much as possible, and [\s\S] basically means "anything". So he takes anything.

```
RegExp parts without escaping, exploded for readability
start tag : %||
first info: ([^|]*) // will stop at the first |
separator : ||
last info : ([^|]*) // will stop at the first |
end tag   : ||%

Escaped RegExp:
/%\|\|([^\|]*)\|\|([^\|]*)\|\|%/g
```

Comment: This regex won't match values like `%||123456|7890||Joe||%`

Comment: You're not supposed to use the delimiting character in the values. But from the exemples given, it won't happen.

Comment: From the examples given, the delimiter is a 2-char string.